# What's the correct data structure for 2-prop sorted list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I am writing a simple handless ui framework, in which i need to dispatch all the message by my own.

Every widget has a list of child, which has two properties: paint order(the order to recieve paint message) and other-event order(the order to receive message other than paint).

```
void Widget::sortChildWidgets( SortMode mode )
{
    if (mode == kSortByPaint) {
        //return true if should precede otherwise return false;
        m_children.sort([&](Widget* pw1, Widget* pw2) ->bool {
            if (pw1->getPaintOrder() < pw2->getPaintOrder()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    if (mode == kSortByEvent) {
        //return true if should precede otherwise return false;
        m_children.sort([&](Widget* pw1, Widget* pw2) ->bool {
            if (pw1->getEventOrder() < pw2->getEventOrder()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Because widget could change its order at runtime, i need to resort everytime i dispatch any message, which definitly is too bad.

My problem: Is there any better data structure rather than std::list to free me from sort every time dispatch message, Or i need to maintain too std::list and make it sorted everytime i insert an child to a widget?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended data-structure for keeping items ordered is an `std::set`. You can provide a custom predicate for the ordering, and thus keep the same items in multiple sets with different ordering.

If you need more performance, you could look into [Boost.Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). This is a library designed to keep multiple views of the same data-set with different orderings.

Note that neither of these data-structure assume that the value of a key does not change once it has been added.

Comment: In this project, I could not use heavy-library such as boost. Maybe, I would need to maintain one std::list, two std::set!!!

Comment: @Jichao: Are you sure that you need an `std::list`? An `std::vector` is almost always more efficient.